# systemctl cannot start service (code=exited status =0/success)

Tags: linux, centos-7, systemd, systemctl

I installed Shadowsocks-r in my CentOS 7 server, and I want to use systemd to manage it. So I created a file in /etc/systemd/system called shadowsocks-r.service.

shadowsocks-r.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks-R Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/shadowsocks/server.py -c /etc/shadowsocks-r/config.json -d start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/shadowsocks-r stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But the service couldn't be started correctly. When checking the status of the service, below is what I get:

```
shadowsocks-r.service - Shadowsocks-R Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shadowsocks-r.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-05-14 10:29:46 UTC; 8s ago
Process: 19267 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/shadowsocks-r stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 19234 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/shadowsocks-r start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 19234 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started Shadowsocks-R Server.
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19234]: 2019-05-14 10:29:46 INFO     util.py:94 loading libcrypto from libcrypto.so.10
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19234]: 2019-05-14 10:29:46 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19234]: IPv6 support
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19234]: Starting ShadowsocksR success
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19267]: 2019-05-14 10:29:46 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19267]: IPv6 support
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19267]: stopped
May 14 10:29:46 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19267]: Stopping ShadowsocksR success
```

The messages shadowsocks-r is from the start and stop function. From the message it seems both start and stop function were executed. Why this happened and what i should do to correct it? thanks!

---

Update:

After running `systemctl start shadowsocks-r.service` I tried running `journalctl -xe` and this is what I get:

```
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started Shadowsocks-R Server.
-- Subject: Unit shadowsocks-r.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit shadowsocks-r.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest polkitd[1547]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:19521:1303198 (system bus name :1.57, object path
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19527]: 2019-05-14 11:09:01 INFO     util.py:94 loading libcrypto from libcrypto.so.10
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19527]: 2019-05-14 11:09:01 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19527]: IPv6 support
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19527]: Starting ShadowsocksR success
May 14 11:09:01 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19560]: 2019-05-14 11:09:01 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
May 14 11:09:02 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19560]: IPv6 support
May 14 11:09:02 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19560]: stopped
May 14 11:09:02 vultr.guest shadowsocks-r[19560]: Stopping ShadowsocksR success
```

------Update------

Now I tried a few more and it's confirmed that the systemctl command actually stopped the process even when I used the command "start". Here is what I tried:

1. First I start the process by `/etc/init.d/shadowsocks-r start`

And the terminal returns:

```
IPv6 support
2019-05-16 08:39:30 INFO     util.py:94 loading libcrypto from libcrypto.so.10
2019-05-16 08:39:30 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
started
Starting ShadowsocksR success
```

2. Then I run `systemctl start shadowsocks-r.service`
3. Then I run `/etc/init.d/shadowsocks-r status`, and the result is: `ShadowsocksR is stopped`

So even when I started the shadowsocks-r process using other method, the systemctl will kill it even when I try to start it.

4. Running `systemctl status shadowsocks-r.service`, here is what I get:

```
    shadowsocks-r.service - Shadowsocks-R Server
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shadowsocks-r.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-16 08:45:10 UTC; 12min ago
    Process: 713 ExecStop=/usr/local/shadowsocks/server.py -c /etc/shadowsocks-r/config.json -d stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 686 ExecStart=/usr/local/shadowsocks/server.py -c /etc/shadowsocks-r/config.json -d start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Main PID: 686 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[686]: 2019-05-16 08:45:10 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[686]: 2019-05-16 08:45:10 ERROR    daemon.py:75 already started at pid 670
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[686]: IPv6 support
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[686]: IPv6 support
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest systemd[1]: shadowsocks-r.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[713]: 2019-05-16 08:45:10 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[713]: IPv6 support
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest server.py[713]: stopped
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Unit shadowsocks-r.service entered failed state.
    May 16 08:45:10 vultr.guest systemd[1]: shadowsocks-r.service failed.
```

-------Update --------

Per @Daniel B's suggestion, I removed the ExecStop line in the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks-R Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/shadowsocks/server.py -c /etc/shadowsocks-r/config.json -d start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I first stop the server.py process by `/etc/init.d/shadowsocks-r stop` and it reuturns `ShadowsocksR is stopped`

Then I run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start shadowsocks-r.service
systemctl status shadowsocks-r.service
```

I still get the error message, and it seems the systemctl command couldn't start the process (before it can start then stop the process)

```
shadowsocks-r.service - Shadowsocks-R Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shadowsocks-r.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-05-16 09:40:43 UTC; 29s ago
  Process: 2964 ExecStart=/usr/local/shadowsocks/server.py -c /etc/shadowsocks-r/config.json -d start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2964 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 16 09:40:43 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started Shadowsocks-R Server.
May 16 09:40:43 vultr.guest server.py[2964]: 2019-05-16 09:40:43 INFO     util.py:94 loading libcrypto from libcrypto.so.10
May 16 09:40:43 vultr.guest server.py[2964]: 2019-05-16 09:40:43 INFO     shell.py:74 ShadowsocksR 2.8.2
May 16 09:40:43 vultr.guest server.py[2964]: IPv6 support
```

Comment: After attempting to start the service, run `journalctl -xe`, it should give you some extended output.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I try running journalctl -xe and I append the result to my original question.

Comment: I think your service file is fine, perhaps there is something stopping `server.py` from launching correctly? Have you manually called your ExecStart command?

Comment: No I didn't. I noticed the result lists out two processes (start and stop), which I didn't see when running other systemctl command. I'm not sure if that's normal or if that hints anything.

Comment: Hm... it normally stops you from doing this, but did you `systemctl daemon-reload` after saving the file?

Comment: Yes I did. Every time I edited the service file I need to daemon-reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not specifying the [`Type`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=). By default, it is `simple`, which expects that the service process not exit.

According to [the project page](https://github.com/shadowsocksr-backup/shadowsocksr), running in the foreground is as simple as not passing `-d start`.

The complete unit file would look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks-R Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/shadowsocks/server.py -c /etc/shadowsocks-r/config.json

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Systemd will automatically take care of monitoring the process, restarting and stopping it as requested/required.

Comment: I removed the ExecStop line but the problem persisits. I updated my question to reflect the return after I made the change.

Comment: @Ch3_ong Please read my answer again, fully. You *must* change the `ExecStart` line or you *must* specify a `Type` (which has more implications).

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I remove the "-d start" and it worked! Though I don't quite understand how this happened (and I couldn't figure out why running in the foreground is as simple as not passing "-d start"), I appreciate your advice!

Comment: How to run a program in the background or foreground is entirely specific to the program. It’s really just a matter of reading the documentation. `-d start` is probably meant as an abbreviation for `daemon start`.

Comment: Yes it means to start in the background. I don't understand why I need to remove this specification to make things go right ...

Comment: Because `Type=simple` expects to program to *not* run in the background. That’s all. For `Type=forking`, you’d ideally have a PID file, which this service may or may not be able to create. It’s generally not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

put this on service

```
RemainAfterExit=true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).